# Tengo un error al agregar tarifas extra (add_fee) en el carrito de Wordpress con Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

que tal?

Lo que estoy queriendo hacer es lo siguiente: Tengo en el sitio dos tipos de suscripciones para los clientes, que si los compran podran tener descuentos en productos. Estas suscripciones cuestan $5000 y $10000 respectivamente. Lo que quiero hacer es que si un cliente agrega al carrito un producto de por ejemplo $1500, se le de la opcion por medio de una ventanita modal de poder comprar alguna de las dos suscripciones restandole el monto del producto. Es decir que podrian pagar extra $3500 para la de $5000 o $8500 para la de $10000.

Logré hacer el codigo en la pagina del carrito para que pase esto. Me agrega la tarifa extra si es que se elije alguna de las dos opciones, pero cuando por ejemplo pasan al checkout desaparece la tarifa, o bien cuando cambian el metodo de envio o de pago.

Busco la manera de que esta tarifa extra se quede fija tanto si se cambia el metodo de envio o de pago, o si se pasa del carrito al checkout.

Les muestro el codigo que hice:

```
add_action( "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees", "add_fee_extra_para_completar_suscripcion_en_carrito", 10, 1 );

function add_fee_extra_para_completar_suscripcion_en_carrito( $cart ) {        

        global $woocommerce;        

        $TOTAL_COMPRA = intval(WC()->cart->get_subtotal());  
    
        $SUMA_CLASICA = 5000 - $TOTAL_COMPRA;   
        $SUMA_PREMIUM = 10000 - $TOTAL_COMPRA;  

        $URL_COMPRA_SUSC_CANCEL = 'https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/?compra-susc=cancel';  
        $URL_COMPRA_SUSC_CLASICA_OK = 'https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/?compra-susc=clasica-ok';  
        $URL_COMPRA_SUSC_PREMIUM_OK = 'https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/?compra-susc=premium-ok';  
        $URL_CARRITO = 'https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/';
        $URL_ACTUAL = get_permalink();

        $COMPRA_SUSC = $_REQUEST['compra-susc'] ?? '';  


        if (is_page('cart') || is_page('checkout')) {

            if ($TOTAL_COMPRA < 5000) {  

                if ( !usuario_rol( 'Premium' ) && !usuario_rol( 'Clasico' ) ) {     
    
                    if ($COMPRA_SUSC == '') {
                    ?>
                    <div id="modalExtraParaSusc" class="modal fade show">                                               <!--background-color: #202020;-->
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: #202020; border-radius: 8px; color: white; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px;">
                                <div class="modal-header" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 28px 36px 0px 36px; border: 0;">                           
                                    <p style="flex-direction: row; padding-bottom: 20px; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">Puede completar su compra para la obtención de una de nuestras dos suscripciones:</p>                                                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:0;">
                                    <div style="padding: 0px 50px;">
                                        <table cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="product-name" colspan="2" style="border-width:3px;">Total del carrito</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
                                        <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr class="cart-subtotal">
                                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                                    <td data-title="Subtotal"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi style="color: white;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol" style="color: white;">$</span> <?php echo $TOTAL_COMPRA; ?> </bdi></span></td>
                                                </tr>                                               
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>                                
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 0;">
                                    <form action="https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/" style="padding: 0px 50px;">                                
                                        <label style="color: white;">
                                            <input type="radio" name="compra-susc" value="clasica-ok"/>
                                            Resto para suscripción Clásica de $5000: $ <?php echo $SUMA_CLASICA; ?> 
                                        </label>
                                        <label style="color: white;">
                                            <input type="radio" name="compra-susc" value="premium-ok"/>
                                            Resto para suscripción Premium de $10000: $ <?php echo $SUMA_PREMIUM; ?> 
                                        </label>  
                                        <!--    
                                        <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">
                                            <tbody>                                             
                                                <tr class="order-total">
                                                    <th>Total</th>
                                                    <td data-title="Total"><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi style="color: white;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol" style="color: white;">$</span>375,00</bdi></span></strong> </td>
                                                </tr>   
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>   
                                        -->
                                        <p class="enlace-ver-susc" style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 50px;">Ver nuestras <a href="https://cherimoya.com.ar/suscripciones" style="color: #c207b2;">Suscripciones</a> </p>  
                                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; margin-top: 30px;">  
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="width: 200px; height: 40px; padding: 0px 12px 4px 12px; background-color: #9ce52e !important;    color: #1f2614;">
                                                Aceptar                                               
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 200px; padding: 0; margin-right: 0;">
                                                <a href="https://cherimoya.com.ar/cart/?compra-susc=cancel" style="display: block; height: 38px; border: 2px solid #9ce52e !important; background-color: #202020; color: #9ce52e !important;">Cancelar</a>                                         
                                            </button>                                                                            
                                        </div>                                   
                                    </form>   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <style>
                        #modalExtraParaSusc {
                            display: block;
                            position: fixed;
                            top: 0;
                            right: 0;
                            bottom: 0;
                            left: 0;
                            z-index: 1050;                 
                            outline: 0;
                            transition: opacity .15s linear;
                            background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
                            overflow-x: hidden;
                            overflow-y: auto;
                        }
    
                        #modalExtraParaSusc > div {
                            margin-top: calc((100vh - 536px) /2) !important;
                            max-width: 500px;
                            margin: 1.75rem auto;
                            position: relative;
                            width: auto;
                            /*pointer-events: none;*/
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                } 

                
                
                if ($COMPRA_SUSC == 'clasica-ok') {  
                    $additional_fee_name = "Resto para suscripción Clásica";
                    $extra_fee = $SUMA_CLASICA;
                    $additional_fee_taxable = true;

                    $addedFee = false;

                    // first check to make sure it isn’t already there
                    foreach ( $cart->get_fees() as $_fee ) {                            
                        if ($_fee->id == sanitize_title($additional_fee_name) ) {
                            $_fee->amount = (float) esc_attr( $extra_fee );
                            $_fee->taxable = $additional_fee_taxable;
                            $addedFee = true;
                        }                                            
                    }
                    if (!$addedFee) {                       
                        $cart->add_fee( __($additional_fee_name, "woocommerce"),
                        $extra_fee, $additional_fee_taxable );                               
                    }
                }

                if ($COMPRA_SUSC == 'premium-ok') {                       
                    $additional_fee_name = "Resto para suscripción Premium";
                    $extra_fee = $SUMA_PREMIUM;
                    $additional_fee_taxable = true;

                    $addedFee = false;

                    // first check to make sure it isn’t already there
                    foreach ( $cart->get_fees() as $_fee ) {                                                
                        if ($_fee->id == sanitize_title($additional_fee_name) ) {
                            $_fee->amount = (float) esc_attr( $extra_fee );
                            $_fee->taxable = $additional_fee_taxable;
                            $addedFee = true;
                        }                                             
                    }
                    if (!$addedFee) {                     
                        $cart->add_fee( __($additional_fee_name, "woocommerce"), $extra_fee, $additional_fee_taxable );                               
                    }
                }    
            }  
        } 
           
}
```

Aguardo respuestas. Gracias